# Qt C++:Signal and Slot Argument are not compatible

Tags: c++, qt, qml, signals-slots

I don't know what the issue with this code, the syntax I have used for connecting the signals and sort looks correct but for some reason I keep getting this error

```
error: static assertion failed: Signal and slot arguments are not compatible.
 #  define Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(Condition, Message) static_assert(bool(Condition), Message)
                                             ^
```

this is the code for the header file

```
include <QString>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QTextStream>

class filereader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_PROPERTY(QString filename READ getFileName WRITE setFileName NOTIFY fileNameChanged) 
    Q_PROPERTY(QString output READ getOutput) 
    Q_PROPERTY(QString error READ getErrorString)

    explicit filereader(QObject *parent = 0);

    QString getFileName();
    QString getOutput();
    QString getErrorString();

    void setFileName(const QString &fileName);

    Q_INVOKABLE void readFile(); // this allows us to use this is as a function so we could do something like onClicked{ <text_id>.text = <file_reader_id>.readFile() }
signals:
    void fileNameChanged();
    void outputChanged(QString &Output);
    void gotError(QString &&err);
    void errorSignal();
protected slots:
    void handleOut(QString &output);
    void handleError(QString &err);
private:
    QString fileName;
    QString output;
    QString error;
};

#endif // FILEREADER_H
```

this is the code for the source file

```
#include "filereader.h"

filereader::filereader(QObject *parent):    
    QObject(parent)
{
    connect(this,&filereader::gotError,this,&filereader::handleError);
    connect(this,&filereader::outputChanged,this,&filereader::handleOut);
}

QString filereader::getFileName()
{
    return this->fileName;
}

QString filereader::getOutput()
{
    return this->output;
}

QString filereader::getErrorString()
{
    return this->error;
}

void filereader::setFileName(const QString &fileName)
{
    if(this->fileName == fileName)
        return;
    this->fileName = fileName;
    emit fileNameChanged();
}

void filereader::readFile()
{
    QFile file(this->fileName);
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
       QTextStream in(&file);
       while (!in.atEnd())
       {
          QString line = in.readAll();
          outputChanged(line);
          qDebug() << line;
       }
       file.close();
       file.flush(); // this flushes the file stream
    }else{
        gotError("Could not open the file!");
    }
}

void filereader::handleOut(QString &output)
{
    if(this->output == output)
        return;
    this->output = output;
}

void filereader::handleError(QString &err)
{
    if(this->error == err)
        return;
    this->error = err;
    emit errorSignal();
}
```

I'm new to Qt and Qml so please help me understand the issue. Thanks :)

Comment: Change `void gotError(QString &&err);` to `void gotError(QString &err);`.

Comment: Usually you want const QString&. Here i would not use slots at all though and just call the methods directly.

Comment: @KernelPanic the reason I can't use ```void gotError(QString &err);``` because most of the times it is used like ```gotError("Could not open the file!");```  so it's like using a reference for a lvlaue

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld my main motive is to try out stuff with signals and slots, that's why I'm using them rather than using normal methods. I don't get what you mean by ```Usually you want const QString&.``` . It would be awesome if you could do a small writeup.

Comment: With `const QString&` this `gotError("Could not open the file!")` should work.

Comment: @drescherjm yeah that worked but doesn't solve the error. Could you also explain to why using const reference wont give an error?

Comment: The default way to pass an argument is a const reference, not a mutable one. Unless you want to modify the string in the slot (i wouldn't know a use case for that), const reference prevents unwanted modifications and allows you to use temporary values (rvalues).

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! The issue was as read from another stack overflow answer was due to adding a new instance of the QObject which needed rerun qmake and on doing this my errors vanished.